# npm install returns Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

All of a sudden, when updating the packages in my app using `npm install`, I get the following error:

```
module.exports = async process => {
                       ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Having searched SO I have made sure that I'm running a recent version of Node (16.14.2), set the default alias to be this version, and removed older versions of node. My setup is now as follows:

```
{
  'app-name': '1.0.0',
  npm: '8.5.0',
  node: '16.14.2',
  v8: '9.4.146.24-node.20',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.45.1',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '1.1.1n+quic',
  cldr: '40.0',
  icu: '70.1',
  tz: '2021a3',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

I can't update npm, or install npm directly using `curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh`, which just returns 'Failed!'.

This is on a production server, so I'm looking to avoid complete re-installs, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The path to node was being modified by two files in my Bitnami distribution, which prevented the correct version being used.

I found the solution was to add /usr/local/bin to the path that gets exported from ~/.bashrc and /opt/bitnami/.bitnamirc, as described below.

https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-to-upgrade-nodejs-in-bitnami-server/57857/21?page=2